# Time series dataframe fill values with same period data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains NaN values and I want to fill the missing data using information of the same month.

the dataframe looks this:

```
data = {'x':[208.999,-894.0,-171.0,108.999,-162.0,-29.0,-143.999,-133.0,-900.0],
       'e':[0.105,0.209,0.934,0.150,0.158,'',0.333,0.089,0.189],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01',
                                '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01',
                                '2020-02-01','2020-03-01',
                               '2020-01-01','2020-02-01',
                               '2020-03-01'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['e'] =df['e'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Now im using `df=df.fillna(df['e'].mean())` to fill the nan value but it takes all the column data, is and it gives me `0.27` is there a way to use only the data of the same month?, the result should be `0.56`

Comment: What if all values for one month are `NaNs`?

Comment: Maybe the correct way of filling the data will be a 0

Comment: I would drop the rows where there are only `NaNs` for the entire month. Otherwise interpolation can fill the gaps with fairly realistic values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try grouping in index.month and get mean (`transformed`) then fillna

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
out = df.fillna({'e':df.groupby(df.index.month)['e'].transform('mean')})
```

---

```
print(out)
                  x       e
2020-01-01  208.999  0.1050
2020-02-01 -894.000  0.2090
2020-03-01 -171.000  0.9340
2020-01-01  108.999  0.1500
2020-02-01 -162.000  0.1580
2020-03-01  -29.000  0.5615
2020-01-01 -143.999  0.3330
2020-02-01 -133.000  0.0890
2020-03-01 -900.000  0.1890
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `interpolate()` instead of `fillna()`, but you have to sort the index first, ie.:

```
df.e.sort_index().interpolate()
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01    0.1050
2020-01-01    0.1500
2020-01-01    0.3330
2020-02-01    0.2090
2020-02-01    0.1580
2020-02-01    0.0890
2020-03-01    0.9340
2020-03-01    0.5615
2020-03-01    0.1890
Name: e, dtype: float64
```

By default linear interpolation is used, so in case of a single occurrence of NaN you get the mean value and the missing one was replaced by 0.5615 like you expected. However if the `NaN` was the first sample of the month after sorting the result would be the mean of the last month's last value and this month's next value, but it works in cases where there are `NaNs` for the whole month and nothing to average, so depending how strict you are on the same month requirement or how are your missing values spread across the whole dataframe you can accept this solution or not.